# Vue 2.5 vue-class-component uses Vue namespace but it's a Type

Tags: typescript, vue.js

After upgrading my Vue 2.0 Typescript project that uses `vue-class-component` to Vue 2.5, I get the following error in the declaration file:

```
ERROR in /myproject/node_modules/vue-class-component/lib/declarations.d.ts

(6,33): error TS2702: 'Vue' only refers to a type, 
but is being used as a namespace here.
```

Indeed, the `declaration.d.ts` seems to use `Vue` as a namespace:

```
options: Vue.ComponentOptions<Vue>
```

But how can I fix this? Is this an oversight/glitch in the declaration file of `vue-class-component`?

The whole declaration file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export declare type VueClass = {
    new (): Vue;
} & typeof Vue;
export declare type DecoratedClass = VueClass & {
    __decorators__?: ((options: Vue.ComponentOptions<Vue>) => void)[];
};
```

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it by importing componentoptions explicitly, this seems to work:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import {ComponentOptions} from 'vue'

let options : ComponentOptions<Vue>;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - where did you apply this change? At vue-class-component's declaration.d.ts? It doesn't make sense to me - i.e. it might work locally, but for PaaS deployment (like heroku or similar) I would need to run some post-deploy script (a smelly one to be honest)

Comment: As already requested by previous comment: Where did you apply this change?! I have the same problem and I don't know where to place this snippet. If I place it directly in the declaration.d.ts I'll get a new error:
error TS1046: A 'declare' modifier is required for a top level declaration in a .d.ts file

Comment: It's in my vue SFC component (for example, helloworld.vue): `<script lang="ts">import Vue, { ComponentOptions }  from 'vue'`I haven't run into this error lately, maybe because I now use the `vue-class-component` or Vue has updated their typings file?

Answer (score 2):

Vue's declaration files recently updated, so make sure both `vue-class-component` and `vue` are up-to-date. Because of the update, you may have to reference types in the following way:

```
import Vue, * as VueTypes from "vue"

let x: VueTypes.ComponentOptions<any>;
```

Comment: I did update all packages. I found a similar solution by just importing the options.

Comment: When I update the packages using `npm update vue-class-component` or even `install` then I do not get the latest version from github: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/blob/master/src/declarations.ts The github version seems to be updated already. Is there another step required?